# Resulting object size too big when rbind-ing data frames

Tags: r, rbind

I have saved my data as an rda file (size 71MB). Then, so it is easier to work with it, I have partitioned it into 12 data frames, which I have also saved as rda files.

For the final step of my work, I need to have all the data in one single data frame again, so I have rbind-ed the smaller files into one.

An example would be the following:

```
load("A1.rda")
load("A2.rda")
load("A3.rda")
load("A4.rda")
load("A5.rda")
load("A6.rda")
load("A7.rda")
load("A8.rda")
load("A9.rda")
load("A10.rda")
load("A11.rda")
load("A12.rda")
C <- rbind(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12)
save(C,file="c.rda")
```

I would expect the "c.rda" file to be the same size as the original "a.rda" file. However, my "c.rda" file is much, much bigger than the original file (on the order of 15 times bigger).

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Are you expecting the files to be identical? If not, why would it matter? I would suggest checking the rowcounts as a basic sanity check and then examining the data types of the columns in C -- do you have any values that were integer valued but are now character factors? Etc.

Comment: The original file is 71MB. I'm rbinding the smaller files in steps. I have bound 7 out of the 12 files already. And the resulting file (just over half way through) is of size 790MB. I'm worried that, if it is taking so much more space in the hard disk, is it also taking much more RAM? The row and col counts are good. 14 out of the 15 cols are factors and they seems to be good, too. The remaining col is numeric and also seems to be good.

Comment: Well, don't know what to tell ya, I checked you procedure with a sample data set and got the exact size of the object back. My guess would be that you are modifying the data in some way or you are not storing the objects in the way you think you are. To be of any more help we would need your code and a `dput` of some of your data.

Comment: thanks @mkemp6! the data is confidential so, unfortunately, can't share. I'm going through 'The R Inferno' now, see if I can't work out what's going on. I'll post if I find an explanation.